# Run SharePoint STSADM command from C# Console

Tags: c#, sharepoint, stsadm

I've been asked to run the following command from C#:

```
stsadm -o gl-copylist -sourceurl "http://someurl" -targeturl "http://someurl" -includeusersecurity -haltonfatalerror -deletesource -includedescendants All –nofilecompression
```

Here is the code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/C " + command,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
```

The command runs fine in a stand-alone command window, but always displays the standard "STSADM -o" help text when run from my console app.

Any idea why??

The gl-copylist command is an add-in to the standard SharePoint STSADM command. Could this be the reason? Other standard STSADM commands run in my code.

Comment: It actually wasn't the order. I had used the wrong hyphen character. After replacing it with the right one it works.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an error in method that parses/validates command line arguments in `stsadm` assembly, in particular when `includedescendants` parameter *that accepts value* is specified **before** another parameter the following error occurs:

> Command line error.

```
stsadm -o gl-copylist 
-sourceurl "http://server/sourceweb/listviewpage" 
-targeturl "http://server/targetweb" -includeusersecurity 
-haltonfatalerror 
-deletesource 
-includedescendants All   <- when this parameter is specified before another parameter    
–nofilecompression
```

Once the `includedescendants` parameter is specified as the **last one**, the command is executed successfully:

```
stsadm -o gl-copylist 
-sourceurl "http://server/sourceweb/listviewpage" 
-targeturl "http://server/targetweb" -includeusersecurity 
-haltonfatalerror 
-deletesource 
–nofilecompression
-includedescendants All
```